# How i can remove results of my Query, using LAG function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, window-functions

First of all, srry for my bad english.

I need to calculate the iddle time of an separators group. Actualy i have the following query:

```
USE mydatabase
SELECT p.iddoc as SaleOrder, p.name as Client, u.username as SysUser,

    CONVERT(DATETIME, o.creatdate) as CreateDate,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, o.inidate) as IniDate,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, o.findate) as FinalDate,

      RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, (lag(o.findate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate)), o.inidate) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, (lag(o.findate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate)), o.inidate) % 3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, (lag(o.findate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate)), o.inidate) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) as IdleTime

FROM serviceorder o
    inner join user u on o.usercode = u.codusuario
    inner join requests p on o.idrequest = p.codpedidocab

WHERE u.username like ('USER NAME')
    and o.iduserstart is NOT NULL
    and p.sit = '8'
    and o.creatdate BETWEEN '2020-06-30 00:00:00' and '2020-06-30 23:59:00'
    and o.inidate BETWEEN '2020-06-30 00:00:00' and '2020-06-30 23:59:00'

ORDER BY o.inidate
```

My problem on this query is when "o.inidate is < than a last o.findate", i need to remove the results than have "o.inidate < (lag(o.findate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate))", but i can't this because can't use the LAG on the where.

What do you suggest i do?

Comment: I suggest you add some sample data and expected result. and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use a CTE and then filter in the outer select. Also `inner join user` isn't going to work; `USER` is a reserved keyword and it's use should be avoided for object names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window functions can be used in the `select` and `order by` clauses only. You can use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.iddoc as SaleOrder, 
        p.name as Client, 
        u.username as SysUser,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, o.creatdate) as CreateDate,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, o.inidate) as IniDate,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, o.findate) as FinalDate,
        LAG(o.findate) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate) lagFinalDate,
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, (lag(o.findate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate)), o.inidate) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, (lag(o.findate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate)), o.inidate) % 3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, (lag(o.findate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate)), o.inidate) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) as IdleTime
    FROM serviceorder o
    INNER JOIN [user] u     ON o.usercode  = u.codusuario
    INNER JOIN requests p ON o.idrequest = p.codpedidocab
    WHERE 
        u.username = 'USER NAME'
        AND o.iduserstart is NOT NULL
        AND p.sit = '8'
        AND o.creatdate >= '2020-06-30' 
        AND o.creatdate <  '2020-07-01'
        AND o.inidate   >= '2020-06-30' 
        AND o.inidate   <  '2020-07-01'
) t
where IniDate < lagFinalDate
```

Additional changes to the query:

- half-open interval filters are more accurate (and easier to understand) than `between`
- `u.username like ('USER NAME')` is equivalent to `u.username = 'USER NAME'`
- `user` is a language keyword, hence it needs to be quoted when used as a table name

Comment: "LAG(o.findate) OVER (ORDER BY o.findate) lagFinalDate"
Thanks.